# Android: How to turn on screen when new notification received?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I've tried almost everything and I can't understand how to turn on phone screen when new notification received in background mode.

I'm using FCM. When app is in background, notifications received are managed by system tray. How can I ask system tray to turn on the screen when something new received? Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Finally, the answer is here.

If you are using Firebase API to send notifications from your server to device, **remember** that **onMessageReceived()** method from **extended FirebaseMessagingService** only calls in BACKGROUND if you send notifications like this:

```
                        $msg = array
                        (
                            'body'  => $newsObj['description'],
                        );
                        $fields = array
                        (
                            'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
                            'data'          => $msg,
                            'priority'  => "high"
                        );
```

You see, if you change that "**data**" property to "**notification**", **onMessageReceived()** method only will be called if the app is in **FOREGROUND**.

For turning screen on when new notification is received, put the following code into your **onMessageReceived()** method:

```
        // Turn on the screen for notification
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        boolean result= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH&&powerManager.isInteractive()|| Build.VERSION.SDK_INT< Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH&&powerManager.isScreenOn();

        if (!result){
            PowerManager.WakeLock wl = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,"MH24_SCREENLOCK");
            wl.acquire(10000);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wl_cpu = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"MH24_SCREENLOCK");
            wl_cpu.acquire(10000);
        }
```

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

That's all!

Comment: `PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK` is deprecated, how can it be done without it?

Answer (score 3):

> Try This One

**you have to do one thing, when you are showing notification, you have to Broadcast this intent.after generating notification in `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` method of `FirebaseMessagingService` extended class**

```
Intent in=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED);
        getActivity().sendBroadcast(in);
```

Comment: I'm sending notifications from my server using php. So notifications aren't handled locally on device. Where should I put this code in this case?

Comment: Where you are defining  notification body?

Comment: In php on the server. I'm sending notifications through firebase api.

Comment: from where you calling this notificationManager.notify(); statement ?

Comment: I'm not calling this on device.. the notification automatically appears on the screen after my server run the script. The only problem is that the screen is not turning on and I don't know how to do this.

Comment: have you implemented FirebaseMessagingService anywhere in Device level code.

Comment: I've tried this too. But onMessageReceived method only calls when app is in foreground, not in background.

Comment: I'll try this again when I get home. And what if the app is closed? I'm iOS developer and I m new to android.. :)

Comment: normally it will not get closed but if it happens the surround these two line with try catch block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146113/discussion-between-robert-constantinescu-and-aniruddh-parihar).